# ElasticSearch: query for parts of a dot separated word

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I have an AWS ElasticSearch(v 5.5)/Kibana(v 5.5.2)  instance ingesting my log data from my java service. In my logs I have stack traces with fully qualified exception names (eg. `com.example.MyException`).

My problem is that when I try to search for `MyException` via Kibana I get zero results, but if I search for `com.example.MyException` I get back all the results I expect.

The ElasticSearch [word-delimiter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) documentation says:

> Words are split into subwords with the following rules:
>
> - split on intra-word delimiters (by default, all non alpha-numeric characters)

I expected this to mean that my fully qualified class name would be split by the dots and that I would be able to search just for the class name.

What do I need to do to be able to search for just the class name to get results for ElasticSearch.

**Update**

My logs are getting ingested into ElasticSearch via the [Stream Cloudwatch Logs to EslaticSearch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html) AWS feature. This feature generates an AWS lmbda function which sends the log records to ElasticSearch. I'm using the default generated function ([see code](https://gist.github.com/torgeir/aa3c28c336fc977b9ebf10784bc1a666)). I have not configured any ElasticSearch mappings so I assume that I'm using the defaults from [Dynamic Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html)

Sample log entry:

```
{
    "date": 1516892650443,
    "requestID": "ff5d5a37-01e0-11e8-bf20-610a6080caa5",
    "logger name": "com.example.MyHandler",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "message": "Exception thrown: ",
    "exception": " com.example.MyException \n \tat com.example.MyHandler.handle(MyHandler.java:100) \n \tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) \n \tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) \n \tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) \n Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed\n \tat java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:100)"
}
```

Sample Index configuration:

```
{
  "cwl-2018.01.16": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "MyService-prod": {
        "properties": {
          "@id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "@log_group": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "@log_stream": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "@message": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "@owner": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "exception": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "level": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "logger name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "requestID": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "refresh_interval": "5s",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "blocks": {
          "write": "false"
        },
        "provided_name": "cwl-2018.01.16",
        "creation_date": "1516060800423",
        "number_of_replicas": "0",
        "uuid": "xxxx",
        "version": {
          "created": "5050299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But have you added that filter to your mapping for that field that holds your class name and package?

Comment: No I have not added any filters or mappings to elasticsearch.

Comment: Try searching for `myexception`. Lowercase. And how do you actually search? Do you use the fieldname in the search text box or you just type MyException and that's it?

Comment: I just type my exception name into the kibana search text box. I tried searching with lowercase (ie. ```myexception```) and with the field name (ie. ```exception:myexception```) but still with zero results.

Comment: I have a similar problem with a trailing slash. For example : *"bla :myword/bla"* matches a search on *"myword"* while *"bla;myWord/bla"* does not match ! Quite disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to search for *MyException in Kibana? I used this on my environment and it worked. But you should be cautious with the time range, at first I used 90 days and I had to restart my Elasticsearch. If you specify the field you are looking at than it will be faster, I used "logger: *MySearchExpression" and it worked within a few seconds.

Comment: Yes I have tried this, but when I tried a query with a 15 minute time range the query timedout.

Comment: Sadly, it did not work in my case.